# Can we have two remainders which are identical in value?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For every large $N>0$ is there an $a\in[N,2N]$ such that we have two coprimes $\frac{a}{\log a}<b,c<a$ such that the remainder $a\bmod b$ in interval $[0,b]$ is same as remainder $a\bmod c$ in interval $[0,c]$?

There are roughly $\frac1{\zeta(2)}N^2$ choices of $b,c$ and $N$ ways $a\bmod b$ and $a\bmod c$ can be same for given $a$ and there are $N$ choices of $a$. So expected intersection is $\frac{N\cdot N}{\frac1{\zeta(2)}N^2}={\zeta(2)}>1$. So may be there is such $a,b,c$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are given that there exists a non-negative integer $r<\min\{b,c\}$ such that $a\equiv r\pmod b$ and $a\equiv r\pmod c$. As $\gcd(b,c)=1$ the Chinese remainder theorem tells us that $$a\equiv r\pmod {bc}.$$ 
This implies that
$
a=r+k\cdot bc
$
for some non-negative integer $k$.

- Because $b<a$ we have $r<a$ so we need $k\ge1$.
- Therefore we have $a\ge bc$.
- Therefore we have $a>a^2/\log^2a$.
- Therefore $\log^2a>a$.

But this is impossible for large $a$.

Comment: do you know why counting argument fails here?